# Inner join with update SQL statement throwing an error

Tags: sql

I am writing a SQL statement which is giving an error for inner join with the update.

This is the query:

```
UPDATE trackedentitydatavalue tedv 
INNER JOIN dataelement de ON tedv.dataelementid = de.dataelementid 
SET tedv.value = tedv.value + '_CNCD' 
WHERE de.valuetype = 'TEXT' 
  AND de.optionsetid IS NOT NULL 
  AND RIGHT(tedv.value, 4) != 'CNCD'
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
>   LINE 1: UPDATE trackedentitydatavalue tedv INNER JOIN dataelement de

Comment: Provide which db you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:

```
UPDATE trackedentitydatavalue AS tedv
SET value = value+'_CNCD'  
FROM dataelement de 
WHERE tedv.dataelementid=de.dataelementid
AND de.valuetype='TEXT' 
AND  de.optionsetid is NOT NULL 
AND  RIGHT(tedv.value,4)!='CNCD'
```

Comment: getting error: ERROR:  column "tedv" of relation "trackedentitydatavalue" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Use this prototype

```
update ud u
inner join sale s on
    u.id = s.udid
set u.assid = s.assid
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
UPDATE trackedentitydatavalue tedv 
INNER JOIN dataelement de 
ON tedv.dataelementid = de.dataelementid 
SET tedv.value = concat(tedv.value, '_CNCD') 
WHERE de.valuetype = 'TEXT' 
AND de.optionsetid IS NOT NULL 
AND RIGHT(tedv.value, 4) != 'CNCD'
```